# Why is the Python Requests Module not returning links?

Tags: python, python-requests

So I had created a python web scraper for my college capstone project that scraped around the web and followed links based on a random selection from the page. I utilized Python's request module to return links from a get request. I had it working flawlessly along with a graphing program that showed the program working in real time. I fired it up to show my professor and now the `.links` returns an empty dictionary for every single website.

Originally I had added a skip for any site that returned no links, but now all of them are returning empty. I've reinstalled Python, reinstalled the requests module, and tried feeding the program websites manually and I cannot seem to find a reason for the change.

For reference, I have been using *Portswigger.net* as a baseline to test the `.links` to see if I get them returned. It worked before, and now it does not.

Here is the get request sample:

```
import requests

Url = "https://portswigger.net"

def GetRequest(url):
    with requests.get(url=Url) as response:
        try:
            links = response.links
            if links:
                return links
            else:
                return False
        except Exception as error:
            return error

print(GetRequest(Url))
```

**UPDATE**
So out of the 200 sites I tested this morning, the only one to return links was *kite.com*. It returned the links no problem and my program was able to follow them and collect the data. Literally a week ago the whole program would run fine and return page links from almost every single website.

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: Just added a sample to my q

Comment: What do you expect from `response.links`? From the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.links) I understand that it's supposed to return the links defined as a [http header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link). On the other hand: `https://portswigger.com` returns a 301 to `https://portswigger.net`, so no link would be retrievable (except the http header, maybe?)

Comment: Yeah, `response.links` doesn't do what you want it do do. You'll need to use an HTML parser (beautifulsoup, lxml, etc) to parse the returned HTML and extract the links.

Comment: But why would ```response.links``` work so efficiently before? I guess I'll have to use BeautifulSoup now. Big time re-write is in my future.

Comment: You may not need to do such a rewrite by using [`requests-html`](https://github.com/psf/requests-html#tutorial--usage). Check their examples, you'll find something familiar.

Answer (score 0):

`Requests.Response.links` doesn't work like that [1]. It looks for [Links in the Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link), not link elements in the Response body.

What you want is to extract link *elements* from the Response body, so I would recommend something like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup`.

Seeing as this is fairly common and straight forward and this is a school project, I'll leave that task up to the reader.

[1] - https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.links

Answer (score -1):

Parsing links with `beautifulsoup4` is a possible solution:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links(url: str) -> list[str]:
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
        links = []
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            target = link.get('href')
            if target.startswith('http'):
                links.append(target)

    return links       

links = get_links('https://portswigger.com')
print(*links, sep='\n')

# https://forum.portswigger.net/
# https://portswigger.net/web-security
# https://portswigger.net/research
# https://portswigger.net/daily-swig
# ...
```